# How do I find a value that as two or more associate values in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

For example, I have a table:

ID    Num1     Num2   ThingsToDo

----------------------------------
1     123      ABC    step1
2     123      ABC    step2
3     123      ABC    step3
4     123      ABC    step4
5     456      DEF    step1
6     **123      DEF**    step2 (note: this is the record that i want to filter)
7     456      DEF    step3
8     456      DEF    step4

Question:
How do I find the incorrect row when DEF has two associated values: 123 and 456?
Because in the ID6-step2 the num1 must be 456.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, one mistake: *Because in the ID6-step2 the **num1** must be 456

Comment: instead of posting a comment with a correction, why not edit the question.

Comment: @ Olivier De Meulder   Sorry, I am new at this website. Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will find all distinct values in `Num2` for which there are more than one value in `Num1`:

```
SELECT Num2
 from MyTable
 group by Num2
 having count(distinct Num1) > 1
```

And the following can be used to list all rows containing those problematic `Num2`s:

```
SELECT *
 from MyTable
 where Num2 in (select Num2
                 from MyTable
                 group by Num2
                 having count(distinct Num1) > 1)
```

As for identifying which rows/values are correct or incorrect, that depends upon the business rules you are implementing.

Comment: Tanks @Philip Kelley, your answer solves my problem. Thanks a lot.